# XML / SQLITE DB for use on a CD

Tags: xml, database

I've read a couple of similar questions on SO about this, which is how I've narrowed it down to XML / SqlLite as the best solutions. I need a database for storing data on a CD, doesn't need to be written to or edited and performance isn't a huge issue. There will be less than 100k records.

So, question is, assuming XML is the solution (and from my reading it appears to suit), what do I use for a front-end to query the DB? I need a form-type solution where the user can query and get results, most likely from an EXE or something similar.

I'm familiar with C# asp.net but am I right in thinking that if I code a solution in .net then the user will need the framework for it to work? I need a solution that requires no installation and can be run directly from the CD.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

do you want the app to run always from CD or you want a way to install the package as one...
if thats so you can package it with .net framework and do a silent installation o user's machine

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was a while back now and the project went ahead without my involvement. Thanks for taking the time to reply though.